# How to configure shift + left click to be 'copy link' in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, firefox-extensions

I want to copy some links into clipboard manager; the standard right click -> copy link is not convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to reach the context menu, while using only mouse, is indeed inconvenient.

But since you suggested to configure to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Left click, which is a mixed combination of keyboard key and mouse click, why not use the built-in access key instead?

In Firefox, when you make a right-click on a hyperlink, you will see like screenshot below.

[image: Firefox context menu upon right-click on a hyperlink]

Each menu in list has a letter being underlined, which is what I mean by "access key". For the copy link menu, the letter 'a' in `Copy Link Location` menu is underlined. This means, you can just make selection on this menu by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> on your keyboard.

Therefore, all you need to do is: Right click+<kbd>A</kbd>

For left-handed users: Left click+<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: But I am left handed, do you know the function for selecting "copy link location"? I use keysnail, it will let you bind any key to a function. Thank you!

Comment: @godblessfq Updated answer for left-handed case. I purely assumed that you wanted to know better way of access the "copy link" menu. For the keysnail, you should [ask a new question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask), since that is totally different from your original question.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that tab mix plus add on for Fire fox will sort of do what you want. By setting the ctrl + click to copy url to clipboard. Only problem is that you have to open all the links that you want copied in tabs.

Point is that people want to hold down a button on there keyboard and click a bunch of links and copy them all to the clip board one after another. They have a program watching the clipboard and doing something to those links.

Clearkimura your setup would have the user go click then key and repeat

EX. click then key, click then key, click then key

What we want is hold down a button and click

EX. hold button, click, click, click,

Each click copying the link to the clipboard.